# Teamcity - git stopped working

Tags: git, connection, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

Yesterday we were running out of space on our dev server. I cleaned the of teamcity from `/home/teamcity/buildAgent/logs`. But I don't think it's related...

Today we have found out that none of our git connections in teamcity is working.
But git itself is working from commandline

This is the error message it prints out after pressing `test connection`:

> Connection failed!
>
> Connection test failed: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory

I don't what file it's looking for..? Have you got any ideas?

Here is another relevant log:

http://pastebin.com/aUZWXeLd

Comment: Probably it's trying to write into some files which were there in logs. You need to restart server to get rid of this.

Comment: @Shravan40 you are right! Thank you. I give you the points. Just pls response so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test connection probably trying to write into some files which were there is `logs`. You need to restart the server to get rid of this.

Answer (score 1):

If you stop and start the TeamCity server service this should rectify the issue